# Based on text check the previous checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

I have a set of checkboxes in a dialog box. Onclick of a button this dialog box appears. These checkboxes are followed by anchor tags with some text. These checkboxes are as per some ordered and unordered lists.

There are two cases in this on the way checkboxes are checked.

1. If parent is clicked the respective child checkboxes are also checked.
2. The user can select individual children also.

Here the checkboxes which are parents have their own identifier. But the children has no identifier. If it has also it has one single identifier for all children in the hierarchy.

I need to basically store the checkboxes which are checked in localStorage so that when the page is reloaded i can retrieve the state of the checkboxes which were checked previously.

The first case above happens and works perfectly but in the second case I am not able to retrieve the previous state of individual checkboxes. I tried to send text following the the checkbox which are checked into localStorage and then on page load compared each text with the stored values. If matches then the attribute of the previous elemnt of the text is checked. This is the logic I applied. But it is not working properly.

This is my code

```
function display(){
//some code to display dialog box where the checkboxes along with anchor tags come into picture 

    var vals[];
    $("input[type=checkbox").each(function(){
        vals.push($(this).next("a").text());
    });
//some code which brings in localStorage and the existing data in the dialog
```

the code proceeds further which finally takes all parameters in and checks for the following condition.

```
if ( z[x]==hname[k]){
    alert("Matched");
    $('a[text="'+hname[k]+'"}').prev().attr("checked",true);
}
```

here z[x] is my previous values stored in localStorage and hname[k] is all the values in the dialog box.

Now my problem lies in this line.

```
$('a[text="'+hname[k]+'"]').prev().attr("checked",true);
```

I am trying to check the element previous to the text. But it doesn't work.

My html code::

```
<ul class="test_ex">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref">Fruits</a>

        <ul class="example">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Apple </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Orange </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="test_ex_sample">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref">Birds</a>

                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Peacock </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Parrot </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref"> Food </a>

                        <ul class="example">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Bread </a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="testB" value="OK" />
```

Comment: Would be better if you pos the HTML code.

Comment: I have added a similar HTML which i found on SO :)

Comment: `text="..."` is not a valid HTML attribute, and it is *not* present in the HTML you have provided.

Comment: i will change it to value. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather use the `filter` function:

```
$("a").filter(function (i, e) {
    return 'Birds' === e.innerText.trim();
}).prev().attr("checked", true);
```

checks the checkbox near the anchor containing "Birds" successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the possible solutions:

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="test_ex">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="parent" /> 
        <a class="ref">Fruits</a>
        <ul class="example">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="child" />
                <a class="ref"> Apple </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="child" />
                <a class="ref"> Orange </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="test_ex_sample">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref">Birds</a>

                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Peacock </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Parrot </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref"> Food </a>

                        <ul class="example">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Bread </a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="testB" value="OK" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("ul")
            .find("input[type=checkbox]")
            .prop("checked",this.checked);
});

$("#testB").click(function(){
    var checkedValues = 
        $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).next().text(); //or html() instead of text()
        }).get();
    alert(checkedValues);
});
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/L5z0o5a0/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!